# jQuery.noConflict causes conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a line of code that causes a conflict between an image slider and a search bar that autocompletes :
`$J = jQuery.noConflict();`

I have two scripts before this line : jquery_1-6-4.js and jquery.autocomplete.js which are used to make the search bar autocomplete.
With the jQuery.noConflict line, the image slider works, but the search bar doesn't suggest words. Without it, the search bar works, but the slider doesn't (it disappears)

Comment: Please post the rest of your jQuery code.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/9ysTczR5) this is the head of my index. Not sure what you mean by jQuery code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you put jQuery in no-conflict mode, it releases `$`, which your autocomplete code is attempting to use. If you set `$J = jQuery.noConflict();`, you've aliased jQuery to `$J`; it takes the place of `$`.  You'll need to use `$J` throughout.

```
$J().ready(function() {
    $J("#recherche").autocomplete("get_kw.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: true,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: false,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```